# How to auto deploy from GitLab to Google App Engine Using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'm looking to auto deploy on to the Google App Engine when I push to Gitlab.

I have got my environment variables in GitLab already and have got the .gitlab-ci.yml (below) file but it fails each time

```
   image: nodejs:8.7.0

before_script:
- echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main" | tee 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
- curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
- apt-get update && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

after_script:
  - rm /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
     - echo $DEPLOY_KEY_FILE_PRODUCTION > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
   - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID_PRODUCTION app deploy
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? What did your investigation show so far?